# Confusion about electric permittivity and vacuum permittivity

Tags: electricity

Vacuum permittivity is the capability of an electric field to permeate a vacuum. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_permittivity)

The permittivity of matter is its resistance to an applied electric field. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5x8kj02ar34&ab_channel=BozemanScience)

So how come the verb "permeate" was used for the definition of vacuum "permittivity" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because on [12:39 19 December 2019](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Vacuum_permittivity&type=revision&diff=931530720&oldid=928607994), an anonymous Wikipedia editor decided to replace "permit" with "permeate", leading to potential confusion such as yours. It has now been changed to avoid using the word "permeate". The Wikipedia [Vacuum permittivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_permittivity) article now says "It is a measure of how easily electric field lines are "permitted" to form in vacuum."

Wikipedia is a very useful resource, but it is not a definitive source for physics definitions.

Comment: Wow. My question made a difference somewhere. Thank you!